# Kallithea: Show which branch contains a changeset

Tags: git, rhodecode, kallithea

How can I see which branch contains a changeset in Kallithea (RhodeCode fork)?

We use git and the URL of the changeset looks like this:

```
https://source/repos/my-git-repo/changeset/da2c946d929b5adb2b12c23a50205009802bde54
```

AFAIK you can do this with the command line:

```
git branch -r --contains <commit>
```

Comment: In plain git, I also find useful: `git for-each-ref  --format='%(refname:short)' --count 1 --contains <optional hash, defaults to HEAD> `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to see the corresponding branch using the web interface, on the up right corner of the changeset page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your image I can see "default". But in mine, there is nothing on the left side of the green/orange/red numbers.

Comment: But for other changesets there is the branch. You are right. Mine must be a somehow special changeset....

Comment: Actually, I checked this URL from the project itself: https://kallithea-scm.org/repos/kallithea/changeset/46c6eb7f1d663dbb3c2b02c8be4872d79698a3c8

Comment: Have you checked if this is not a commit in a pull request awaiting for a merge to a branch?

Comment: No, it is not a pull request. Sorry.

Comment: So probably a commit from a removed branch. Such commits remain in the reflog if it has not expired.